# scraping table data from web in R

Tags: r

I am trying to pull table from following link in R

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

url <- "http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_index_result.php?indian_indices=9"
nifty_index <- url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mc_mainWrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/table') %>%
html_table()
nifty_index <- nifty_index[[1]]


Error 

Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Problem is when I hit the link `http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_index_result.php?` gives me a blank page. HTML table is generated once you fill in the date range for index from this link `http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php`

How would I do it in R?

Comment: When I browse the adress, I get an empty page?

Comment: `http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php` this is the link then I had filled the date range in Daily

Comment: Once I select the date range, I get this link `http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_index_result.php?indian_indices=9` ,But when I paste this link to other tab,I get blank page. How to deal with this problem?